# URL Rewrite using PHP router

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I don't using Zend framework, but I found in *bootstrap.php* file there is the code:

```
$configRouter = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_SITE.'/configs/'.SITE_NAME.'/configUrl.ini', 'UrlRewrite');
$routers->addConfig($configRouter,'routes');
```

*ConfigUrl.ini* file content:

```
[UrlRewrite]
routes.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.index.route = ""
routes.index.defaults.module = "www"
routes.index.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.index.defaults.action = "index"

routes.index_captcha.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.index_captcha.route = "captcha.jpg[/]?"
routes.index_captcha.defaults.module = "www"
routes.index_captcha.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.index_captcha.defaults.action = "captcha"

routes.index_download.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.index_download.route = "download[/]?"
routes.index_download.defaults.module = "www"
routes.index_download.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.index_download.defaults.action = "download"
```

And the file *.htaccess* only per line:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

But I don't know how it rewrite urls?

Please help me in this way URL Rewriting using PHP!

Comment: might be worth having a read of http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ to see if you can figure it out... its really not so difficult!

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't want using mod_rewrite

Comment: im not sure if u can rewrite URL's without mod_rewrite on apache...

Comment: In Zend framework has done it using php...

Comment: No they have not. To use url rewriting the HTTP service needs to know what /url/whatever actually means. It does this by using mod_rewrite. Seriously, Google mod_rewrite.